# Eclipse organization: workspaces, working sets, projects, folders, multiple source folders, ....!

Tags: eclipse, organization

There is quite a tier of organization in Eclipse. You can have multiple workspaces, each of which can have projects, these projects can be assigned to working sets, and then each project can have source folders....

How do you use all this organization? Do you even use it all? Working sets are so hidden that I hardly know what they are; are they commonly used, or are they hidden because they are so uncommonly used?

What is even the methodology behind all this? I'd like a good explanation of the recommended way to use all these different organizational layers, because at the moment I basically just have a bunch of random projects in a single workspace (the default %USER%/workspace folder) and it's getting to be quite an alphabetical mess.

So in essence: **How do you keep your Eclipse workspace(s) organized?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I keep a bunch of random projects in a single workspace like you, then set up working sets to show related projects like the project i'm working on and any projects it depends on. Keeping all the projects in one workspace helps keep paths consistent, using working sets hides all the other projects that you don't need to think about.